# Material glitches in my renders

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen with my renders? It's like part of the material doesn't want to show but I'm using a very basic setup.
[image]

It looks even worse with cycles:
[image]

My rock looks perfectly fine though on the viewport.
[image]

Here are the files for it [rock zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ushmFzDvuNBxX43cHiR5e9lEO_nojzXz/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You have an object that is hidden in the viewport but not in render, so make it invisible in render too:

[image]

Comment: OH! Well now don't I feel silly. Thank you!